# Get commandline of process and taskkill

Tags: cmd, wmic

I need some help here.

I am currently trying to kill any process that isn't in a whitelist (command line) like so, however it is not working.:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "whitelist=DcomLaunch RPCSS LocalServiceNetworkRestricted netsvcs LocalService LocalSystemNetworkRestricted NetworkService LocalServiceAndNoImpersonation taskhostex cmd dwm conhost services smss SearchIndexer Isass Explorer csrss conhost cftmon"

for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%I in (
'wmic process get executablepath^,status /format:csv ^| find "\"'
) do (
set "proc=%%~I"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set /p "=%%~I: "<NUL
wmic path win32_process get CommandLine | findstr /i "%whitelist%" >NUL && (
    echo OK
) || (
    echo UNACCEPTABLE!
    taskkill /im "%%~nxI" /f
)
endlocal
)
```

Comment: No `get` in the wmic commandline one.

Comment: @Noodles Thanks man! Missed that. It however is not working and claims all processes are "OK" even if they aren't in the whitelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wmic path win32_process get CommandLine | findstr /i "%whitelist%"
```

In above command, [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) would look for a match in *entire `wmic` output* so it will find a match **always**. For instance, at least `cmd` would match because `wmic` runs in a `cmd` window. Next *commented* code snippet should work however it gives different results if elevated (run as administrator).

```
set "whitelist=DcomLaunch RPCSS LocalServiceNetworkRestricted netsvcs LocalService LocalSystemNetworkRestricted NetworkService LocalServiceAndNoImpersonation taskhostex cmd dwm conhost services smss SearchIndexer Isass Explorer csrss conhost cftmon"

rem add windows VITAL processes !!! incomplete !!!
set "whitelist=svchost ctfmon lsass winlogon %whitelist%"

for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=," %%I in (
    'wmic process get executablepath^,ProcessID^,status^,WindowsVersion /format:csv ^| find "\"'
) do ( 
    set "proc=%%~I"
    set "procID=%%~J"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

    rem debugging:  set /p "=%%~I: "<NUL

    rem debug try: wmic path win32_process where "ProcessID=%%J" get Name 2>NUL | findstr /i "%whitelist%">NUL 2>&1  && (
    rem debug try: wmic path win32_process get executablepath 2>NUL | findstr /i "!proc:/=//!">NUL 2>&1  && (

    wmic path win32_process where "ProcessID=%%J" get CommandLine 2>NUL | findstr /i "%whitelist%">NUL 2>&1  && (
    rem suppress "No Instance(s) Available" report in above line: 2>NUL
        echo OK %%J "%%~I"
    ) || (
        rem UNWANTED: here come inactive processes "cmd", "wmic", "find"
        rem           and maybe more ones that were active in FOR %%I execution time 
        rem           (but loop continues); let's filter them here:
        tasklist /FI "PID eq %%J" /NH | find "%%J" >NUL 2>&1 && (
            echo NO %%J "%%~I"
            rem taskkill /PID "%%~J" /f
        ) || (
            echo XX %%J "%%~I"
            rem inactive at the moment
        )
    )
    endlocal
)
```

[Essential Processes needed to run Windows](https://www.technibble.com/essential-processes-needed-to-run-windows/) (next list may be a bit out of date):

> … here is a list of the essential processes that Windows needs to run
>   correctly.
>
> - System Idle Process
> - explorer.exe
> - taskmgr.exe
> - spoolsv.exe
> - lsass.exe
> - csrss.exe
> - smss.exe
> - winlogon.exe
> - svchost.exe – (There will be a few of these)
> - services.exe
>
> By shutting down anything other than these processes, stand alone
>   Windows should operate fine, however if any of these processes are
>   shutdown, Windows will start to become unstable or unusable.

Comment: This doesn't work and I need to use get CommandLine. This reports even svchost as NO <PID>.

Comment: @JesseBropez sorry; you can get whichever property you want. I'm pretty sure that it reports most `svchost` as `OK <PID>`. Now fixed such that should report (some) `svchost` as `XX <PID>` as well as other non existent processes (e.g. `cmd`, `wmic`, `find` etc. mentioned already in `rem`).

Comment: I see! Thank you for the help JosefZ! I had forgot to add some other critical processes and Windows kept dying :)